# Retrieve the value in a column corresponding to the maximum date in another column (same row)

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a date column, a name column and another column call it A which contains some text. What I want to do is for each name, 'look up' the A value that corresponds to the maximum date (grouped by name). I thought I could do it with an array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(name),date)
```

then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and then a VLOOKUP but for some reason this doesn't seem to work - I get value errors for the date.

Any other ideas?

Comment: theres only one date column and for each A value there is a date. I made sure I formatted date as a short date. MAX(date) seems to work by itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
=MAX(IF(name=TheName,date,0))
```

to get the MaxDate associated with TheName. (This may need a CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER --- I haven't tested it.) You then could try `VLOOKUP` to pull the corresponding value from A. However, that logic might fail if the MaxDate occurs for more than one name (say MyName vs YourName). To guard against that, you could use combined name and date fields and do a lookup with `MATCH` to return `MyIndex`, the index of the the first instance where MaxDate and TheName coincide:

```
=MATCH(name & date, MyName & MaxDate, 0)
```

The use `MyIndex` to extract the corresponding value from A:

```
=INDEX(A, MyIndex)
```

Hope that helps.